# INotifyPropertyChange doesn't fire

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

EDIT: Please refer to the classes structure.
The INotifyPropertyChanged works fine in the ComMethodA situation and fires the event as expected. Why it doesn't work in the ComMethodB situation?

EDIT 2:
Please refer to the view models code.

In my application i have several Views and ViewModels.
All of the ViewModels inherite from ViewModelBase that creates a singleton object of my model let's call it MainModel with the following structure:

```
public class MainModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   public string Name {get; set; }
   public List<ISystem> SystemsList{get;set;}   
   public IComMethod ComMethodA {get;set;}   // TEST 1
   public MainModel()
   {
       ComMethodA = new ClassC();
      // let's assume that the other props are initialized
   }
}

public class System: ISystem, INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
   public IComMethod ComMethodB {get;set;}   // TEST 2
   public System()
   {
      ComMethodB = new classC(); // classC implements INotifyPropertyChanged, IComMethod
   }
}

public class ClassC() : IComMethod, INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public bool isOpen {get;set;}
    public ClassC()
    {
        // ctor..
    }
}
```

ViewModelA:

```
    ctor() 
    {
        MainModel.SystemsList[0].ComMethodB.PropertyChanged += ComMethodB_PropertyChanged;
        MainModel.ComMethodA.PropertyChanged += ComMethodA_PropertyChanged;     
    }
    private void ComMethodB_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
          MessageBox.Show("TextB");
    }
    private void ComMethodA_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      MessageBox.Show("TextA");
    }
```

ViewModel B:

```
MainModel.ComMethodA.isOpen = true; // FIRES event in ViewModelA
MainModel.SystemsList[0].ComMethodB.isOpen = true; // DOESN'T fires event in ViewModelA
```

In ViewModelA i'm implementing the propery changed event for both TEST 1 & TEST 2 properties.
In ViewModelB i'm changing the 'isOpen' property.

The issue is that the event fires only in the 'ComMethodA' scenario but i want it to fire in the 'ComMethodB' scenario.

Thanks

Comment: You have to raise the event. No where in the code presented do you show that the event is being raised. Suggest you create a base view model that has the common functionality and derive the other classes from it

Comment: @Nkosi this is not the purpose of the INotifyPropertyChanged?to fire the event instead of me? 
Also, how do i raise an event of ViewModelA from ViewModelB?

Comment: You need to read up on how to use `INotifyPropertyChanged`. You seem to not understand it's purpose.

Comment: @gr1d3r `INotifyPropertyChanged` is just an interface. It doesn't have actual functionality

Comment: My issue is why the event fires only in the ComMethodA property and not the the ComMethodB. Please refer to the classes structure.
The  INotifyPropertyChanged works fine in the ComMethodA  situation and fires the event as expected.

Comment: @Nkosi this is not a duplicate. please read again my question and reopen it.
Non of the comments or your answer answers my question.

Comment: As FCin said, implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` just means that your class has to have methods with the appropriate parameters and return types, you still have to implement them and call them.

Comment: The interface is implemented. This is NOT the question. 
Can someone explain why TEST 1 situation works good and TEST 2 doesn't? Both implemented the same.Just the hierarchy in the MainObject is different.

Comment: Without seeing the implementation, it is hard/impossible for us to help you finding out what's wrong. Also, how do you know the event is not fired?

Comment: For testing i'm just raising a messagebox with different text when the event fires. So while i'm running my application only the first event fires.

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged is used by WPF data binding implementation to fire events. Perhaps TEST1 situation is hooked up to a view, and TEST2 is not?

Comment: Where is the event raised? Just changing `isOpen` does not automatically raise a `PropertyChanged` event. If your `ViewModelBase` implementation does take care of this, how does it do it?

Comment: @Sentry the model implements the PropertyChanged.
 Anyway, how can i raise the event from the desired ViewModels? Or how can i raise them manually?

Comment: Again, there is no implementation in the code you pasted. Usually the events are raised in property setters, and unless you have a framework like Fody that does weaving for you, something else is happening and no events are being raised. The UI in WPF for instance refreshes some things on user input events without the need for INPC. If you code does implement INPC correctly you should be able to put breakpoints and verify that the event is fired.

Comment: @AlexPaven I'm not using nothing. The issue is not regarding the INPC implementation. It worked fine until now.
What i'm asking is about the event raising from one ViewModel to another.

Comment: Do you have a method that raises the events? If not, implement one. You can then make it internal or public so it's available from other classes. See example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/how-to-implement-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface

Comment: @AlexPaven I'm trying to call to the 'PropertyChanged' from the other view model but i have a conflict here. On the one side i should make it static so i can call it from the secont view model but on the other side, if the method is static i can't reach the viewmodel binded properties.

Comment: Indeed, it shouldn't be static. You should have a reference to an instance of the other viewmodel if you want to manipulate it. And you can't call PropertyChanged directly because it's an event, you should have a method that raises the event. Did you look at the example I linked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is in code that you didn't post. If I had to guess, I'd say it was something with the MainModel singleton in the ViewModelBase class - perhaps ViewModelA/B are getting different instances of the MainModel?

I filled in the blanks in you question's code and it seems to work for me.
Note: I renamed class System to Systems due to namespace conflicts.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApp9
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Setup the ViewModels
            var vmA = new ViewModelA();
            var vmB = new ViewModelB();

            // Test ViewModelB
            vmB.DoIt();
        }
    }

    public class MainModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName]string name = null)
        {
            if (Equals(field, value))
            {
                return false;
            }
            field = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(name);
            return true;
        }
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string name = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
        #endregion

        #region Property List<ISystem> SystemsList
        private List<ISystem> _SystemsList;
        public List<ISystem> SystemsList { get { return _SystemsList; } set { SetProperty(ref _SystemsList, value); } }
        #endregion

        #region Property IComMethod ComMethodA
        private IComMethod _ComMethodA;
        public IComMethod ComMethodA { get { return _ComMethodA; } set { SetProperty(ref _ComMethodA, value); } }
        #endregion

        public MainModel()
        {
            SystemsList = new List<ISystem>() { new Systems() };
            ComMethodA = new ClassC();
        }
    }

    public interface ISystem
    {
        IComMethod ComMethodB { get; set; }
    }
    public interface IComMethod : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        bool isOpen { get; set; }
    }

    public class Systems : ISystem, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName]string name = null)
        {
            if (Equals(field, value))
            {
                return false;
            }
            field = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(name);
            return true;
        }
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string name = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
        #endregion

        #region Property IComMethod ComMethodB
        private IComMethod _ComMethodB;
        public IComMethod ComMethodB { get { return _ComMethodB; } set { SetProperty(ref _ComMethodB, value); } }
        #endregion

        public Systems()
        {
            ComMethodB = new ClassC();
        }
    }

    public class ClassC : IComMethod, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName]string name = null)
        {
            if (Equals(field, value))
            {
                return false;
            }
            field = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(name);
            return true;
        }
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string name = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
        #endregion

        #region Property bool isOpen
        private bool _isOpen;
        public bool isOpen { get { return _isOpen; } set { SetProperty(ref _isOpen, value); } }
        #endregion
    }

    public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public static MainModel MainModel { get; } = new MainModel();

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName]string name = null)
        {
            if (Equals(field, value))
            {
                return false;
            }
            field = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(name);
            return true;
        }
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string name = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
        #endregion
    }

    public class ViewModelA : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ViewModelA()
        {
            MainModel.SystemsList[0].ComMethodB.PropertyChanged += ComMethodB_PropertyChanged;
            MainModel.ComMethodA.PropertyChanged += ComMethodA_PropertyChanged;
        }

        private void ComMethodB_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("TextB");
        }

        private void ComMethodA_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("TextA");
        }
    }

    public class ViewModelB : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ViewModelB()
        {
        }

        public void DoIt()
        {
            MainModel.ComMethodA.isOpen = true; // this fired off the "TextA" messagebox
            MainModel.SystemsList[0].ComMethodB.isOpen = true; // this fired off the "TextB" messagebox
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now.
A single duplicate of interface object intialization made this issue.

Comment: Great, glad I was able to assist. Too bad everyone else got thrown off by the not shown (but implemented) INPC interface.